# Can anyone help me with this? I am not getting the output

Tags: java, compiler-construction

In this program, I am trying get following output on case of operator correction, here, I want get output to check if a string is a valid arithmetic expression, then print valid & if not(ex. a+, B+ or a+b+ or a b= c*d- and so on..) so I have designed this code in Java but, I am not getting output, when I tried for looping to check for checking the issue, but the value was not been changed outside the loop. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InvalidOperatorCheck {

  public static void main(String[] args){
    int i = 0;
    boolean flag = false;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the Expression to test the string");
    String expression = scan.next();

    while (expression.isEmpty()) {
        if (i % 2 == 1) {
            if (expression.equals("+") || expression.equals("-") || expression.equals("/") || expression.equals("*"))
                flag = false;
        }

        if (expression.length() - 1 == i) {
            if (expression.contentEquals("[a-zA-Z]"))
                flag = true;
        } else {
            flag = false;
        }

        i++;
        i++;
    }

    if (flag == false) {
        System.out.println("\nNot Valid\n");
    } else {
        System.out.println("\nValid\n");
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: You created an endless loop that either never runs or never stops. You have to make it possible for your while condition to become false once it is true or the loop will never stop. Currently it will most likely never run because your condition is wrong and you only enter the loop if **nothing** was entered

Comment: @911DidBush if(!expression.isEmpty()) { scan.nextline()

Comment: @Viral Prajapati Check your while condition it should be `while (!expression.isEmpty()) {//here your code}`.

Comment: Well, looks like you've copied your question from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41722828/java-compiler-design-issue-college-practical-work ([cached version](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:dx3k39C7iwsJ:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41722828/java-compiler-design-issue-college-practical-work)) without changing anything ... I wonder if this question also get's deleted soon.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your code like that, after that do the desired editing in your logic.

**Sample Code**

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class InvalidOperatorCheck{

        public static void main(String[] args){
            int i = 0;
            boolean flag = false;

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Enter the Expression to test the string");
            String expression = scan.next();

            while (!expression.isEmpty()) {
                if (i % 2 == 1) {
                    if (expression.equals("+") || expression.equals("-") || expression.equals("/") || expression.equals("*"))
                        flag = false;
                        break;
                }

                if (expression.length() - 1 == i) {
                    if (expression.contentEquals("[a-zA-Z]"))
                        flag = true;
                } else {
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }

                i++;
                i++;
            }

            if (flag == false) {
                System.out.println("\nNot Valid\n");
            } else {
                System.out.println("\nValid\n");
            }    
        }
    }
```